# sed how to substitute when string has "http://" in it?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sed, replace

I have a file `xx` that has the following contents:

```
@base_url = "http://dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/"
```

I want to use sed to eliminate this line (replace with nothing).  I have used this sed technique with several other line successfully, e.g.

```
sed -i 's/require "selenium-webdriver"//' xx
```

But my attempt for the @base_url line isn't working.  I suspect either the " or the // in the http:// are messing it up but I can't seem to fix!

I have tried:

```
$ sed  's/@base_url = "http://dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/"//' xx
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown option to `s'

$ sed  's/@base_url = \"http://dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/\"//' xx
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown option to `s'

$ sed  's/@base_url = "http:\/\/dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/"//' xx
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unknown option to `s'
```

but none worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, use other separator or *escape* the slashes. Your last try misses escape of last slash.

And as pointed out by [@StephaneChazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/stephane-chazelas), escape `dot`'s as well.

And, including [@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) if `sed` is not needed; `grep -Fxv`, where `-F` is fixed string, not regex, would be an option. `-x` makes sure it matches whole lines. `-v` inverts.

A simple (very simple) benchmark with `time -v` seems to favor `sed` though. (GNU variants.)

```
sed 's/@base_url = "http:\/\/dmstaffing-stage\.herokuapp\.com\/"//' xx
```

To delete it completely (not leave blank line) use:

```
sed '/@base_url = "http:\/\/dmstaffing-stage\.herokuapp\.com\/"/d' xx
                                                                |
                                                                +--- Delete
```

Comment: Stricktly speaking, you'd need to escape dots as well. To remove the line completely, use `grep -xF '@base_url = "http://dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/"'`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I assume you meant `grep -vxF`?

Answer (score 4):

Try using another separator:

```
sed  's|@base_url = "http://dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/"||' xx
```

Answer (score 3):

The slashes in the regex are messing up with sed's delimiters.
But you can use [different delimiters](http://stufftohelpyouout.blogspot.it/2010/04/change-seds-pattern-delimiter-character.html) than the slash. For example:

```
sed  's#@base_url = "http://dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/"##' xx
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the slashes, like `sed -e 's/"@base_url = "http:\/\/dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com\/"/d'`. This jungle of `/\/\//\//` is a symptom of what is called LTS (Leaning Toothpick Syndrome). The best way around this is to just use another delimiter, like `;` in your case, or whatever other non-alphanumeric character tickles your fancy today (and isn't included in whatever mangling you have in mind, obviously).