# Find and replace in Linux

Tags: find, command, replace

I want to replace 0/1 with hetero but whenever I am trying to use the known commands it is showing syntax error because the / is aleady part of the command .. Can anyone suggest a command to solve this issue??

Comment: which command have you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed how to substitute when string has "http://" in it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75973/sed-how-to-substitute-when-string-has-http-in-it)

Answer (score 3):

`/` is not mandatory in sed command

```
sed -i -e s:0/1:hetero: file
```

(`-e` is not mandatory if there is a single `sed` command either)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
sed -i 's/\/0\/1/hatero/g' <file_name>
```