# cron job for pure-quotacheck with pure-pw list

Tags: shell-script, pure-ftpd

I want to automate the process of quota checks for a pure-ftp server.

I've read the docs, so I can do that with `pure-quotacheck -d /path2/home -u user`

The simplest method that I could think of is to combine pure-pw list (because it shows the user and the path to home) with the above command, but I don't know how to combine the two.

So far, I came up with:

```
for s r in $(pure-pw list) | {print $1 $2}; do pure-quotacheck -u $s -d $r; done
```

but I get

> syntax error near unexpected token `r'

```
$ pure-pw list

def                 /home/def/./
```

I also need to strip "/./" from the output of pure-pw list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split lines into variables, you can use `read` (although there are a number of caveats, as always when processing text in the shell):

```
pure-pw list | while read s r; do pure-quotacheck -u "$s" -d "$r"; done
```

This allows you to process `$r` before invoking `pure-quotacheck`, *e.g.* to remove the `/./`. You can also do that by processing `pure-pw`'s output, as you suggested:

```
pure-pw list | sed 'sX/./$XX' | while read s r; do pure-quotacheck -u "$s" -d "$r"; done
```

See [sed how to substitute when string has "http://" in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75973/sed-how-to-substitute-when-string-has-http-in-it) for an explanation of the `sed` usage there.

Comment: i know it's been a year, but thank you 